# Default Placement of components in NetBeans Application

Tags: netbeans-platform

I have a NetBeans Platform based application using NetBeans platform 7.1.1. I have various top components with default location defined with annotations (IDE generated). For example:

```
@TopComponent.Registration(mode = "explorer", openAtStartup = true)
```

I'm trying to figure out why the components:

1. Don't open when I start the application
2. When I open them (i.e. using Window->Component name) they open on the editor location instead of the correct one.

Any hints on where to start looking for answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a lack of dependencies, at least on my case. Some of the components were configured to display in the navigator location. Adding the Navigator dependency, which seems to define navigator location, did the trick!